# R: Extract ranges if they harbor values from a vector (many ranges and large vector)

Tags: r

I have a table of ranges (start, stop), which looks something like this:

| ID | start | stop |
| --- | --- | --- |
| x1 | 351525 | 352525 |
| x2 | 136790 | 136990 |
| x3 | 74539 | 74739 |
| x4 | 478181 | 478381 |
| ... | ... | ... |

I also have a vector of positions.

The data can be simulated with:

```
s=round(runif(50,0,500000),0)
# ranges:
# (+200 is random, the difference my be more or less than that, but stop is always higher than start)
ranges=cbind(ID=paste0("x",1:50), start=s, stop=s+200) 

# positions
pos=round(runif(5000,0,500000),0)
```

I want to select all IDs which have at least one position within their range.

I could loop through ranges and pos:

```
library(dplyr)
selected.IDs <- c()
for(r in 1:nrow(ranges)){
  for(p in 1:length(pos)){
    if(between(pos[p],left = ranges[r,2], right  = ranges[r,3])){
      selected.IDs <- append(selected.IDs, ranges[r,1])
      break
    } else{next}
  }
}
```

That works fine (I think).
However, the 'ranges' object has 83,000 rows and there are 180,000 position. It takes a long time to loop through all of them.

Does anyone has an idea how to do that without a loop?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually do this using overlap joins with `data.table::foverlaps`.

```
s <- round(runif(50,0,500000),0)
# ranges:
# (+200 is random, the difference my be more or less than that, but stop is always higher than start)
ranges <- data.table(ID=paste0("x",1:50), start=s, stop=s+200) 

# positions
pos <- round(runif(5000,0,500000),0)
pos <- data.table(start = pos, stop = pos + 1)

setkey(pos, start, stop)
setkey(ranges, start, stop)

res <- foverlaps(ranges, pos, nomatch = 0)
selected.IDs <- res$ID
```

Comment: I have done something like that a couple of times already. Every time I searched for a solution, but ended up having an extended coffee break while R looped through all the rows...  data.table::foverlaps works like a charm. Thanks you!